# Firebase 'add' data to existing document not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document that was created during a registration process that creates a document with the following property:

`username: "GOOOOD"`

Now, I am trying to `add` a new property called `firstName` to the document so it looks like this:

```
username: "GOOOOD"
firstName: "Roger"
```

However, the `add` function doesn't seem to be working:

```js
function ProfileContainer() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState();
  const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");

  // add first and last name
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (user) {
      db.collection("users").doc(user).collection("profile").doc(user).add({
        firstName: firstName,
      });
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="profileContainer">
            <div className="name__input">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="First Name"
                onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                value={firstName}
              />
            </div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Update</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, the `add` function doesn't seem to be working.

I get the following error:

> TypeError: *firebase_utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_.db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).doc(...).add is not a function

`set` seems to work but I don't want to delete the entire document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add()` **always** creates a new document.  If that's not what you're trying to do, then you shouldn't use it.

If you're trying to add a new field to an existing document, then you should use [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) instead, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).

```
      db.collection("users").doc(user).collection("profile").doc(user).update({
        firstName: firstName,
      });
```

Comment: Thanks, Doug! You're the best!